# Is it possible to set/change output sizes in Create ML for style transfer models?

Tags: coreml, coremltools

When I train a style transfer model in `Create ML`, the default output size is `512x512`. How to change/increase this? Can it be done programatically? All my model predictions outputs are `512x512` in size, even if the **input** image is `4000x4000`. I am quite new with `coreml` stuff.

Comment: It should be possible to add flexible shapes using `coremltools`.